# Java.lang.Assertion Error in junit testing

Tags: java, junit

am trying to write unit tests that checks superUserPrivilege. Here is the code

```
private void checkSuperUserPrivilege(Role r) {
        if (r.getRole().equals(RoleConstants.SUPERUSER)
                && !Context.hasPrivilege(PrivilegeConstants.ASSIGN_SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_ROLE)) {
            throw new APIException("User.you.must.have.role", new Object[] { RoleConstants.SUPERUSER 
        }
    }
```

here is my test

```
@Test
    public void createUser_shouldNotAllowAssigningSuperUserRoleIfCurrentUserDoesNotHaveAssignSystemDeveloperPrivileges() throws IllegalAccessException {
    //setup the currently logged in user
        User currentUser = new User();
        Role userRole = new Role("User Adder");
        userRole.setRole(RoleConstants.AUTHENTICATED);
        userRole.addPrivilege(new Privilege("Add Users"));
        currentUser.addRole(userRole);

        // setup our expected exception
        // we expect this to fail because the currently logged-in user lacks a privilege to be
        // assigned to the new user
        expectedException.expect(APIException.class);
        expectedException.expectMessage("You must have the role '{0}' in order to assign it"); 

        // set current user to the user defined above
       withCurrentUser(currentUser()->{
        // create a role to assign to the new user
            //here the logic is that the current user cannot assign  a user to superuser role because he 
                 lacks AssignSystemDeveloper privliges
            Role role= new Role("add user");
            role.setRole(RoleConstants.SUPERUSER);
            // add a privilege to the role
            role.hasPrivilege(PrivilegeConstants.ASSIGN_SYSTEM_DEVELOPER_ROLE);         

            // create our new user object with the required fields
            User u = new User();
            u.setPerson(new Person());
            // assign the specified role to the user
            u.addName(new PersonName("yon", "g", "sharf"));
            u.setUsername("sharf");
            u.getPerson().setGender("M");
            u.isSuperUser();
            u.addRole(role);
            // here we expect the exception to be thrown
            userService.createUser(u, "something");
        });
    }
```

but here the test still fails am still confused . i need help of how to go over this thanks

Comment: "the test still fails", why does it fails? which assert fails? have you debugged your test?

Comment: How do you set Privilege in the Context? It seems to be a singleton , and in your test you are assigning PrivilegeConstants to the role instance. Have you tried debugging the issue, to see where you have the problem?

Comment: Sure PrivilegConstants is a constant , i would like your way of how you can write a logic depending on the test method  format

Comment: Actually according to how this can be resolved, was to change in the message.properties classes where i defined the arfument ""You must have the role '{0}' in order to assign it"); ' that was the error only